# Several add-ons throw error "DLL load failed. %1 is not a valid Win32 application."

Tags: python, add-on, error, theme

Known add-ons with this issue are Tissue, RetopoFlow, and XNALara/XPS Import/Export.  I am running Blender 2.79 on Windows 10 64-bit.  I have also experienced this issue in 2.78, but not in 2.77.

Edit: This also occurs when I try to switch themes.

Comment: Are you using blender 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: Sounds like you might have the wrong addon binary version either of Blender, the addons or both for your OS version, 32 vs 64 bits

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Close Blender
- Rename *C:\Users\YourNameHere\AppData\Roaming\Blender

  Foundation\Blender\2.79* to
  *C:\Users\YourNameHere\AppData\Roaming\Blender

  Foundation\Blender\2.79.bak*
- Use your login in Windows instead of *YourNameHere* and your version
  of Blender instead of *2.79*
- Start Blender again

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause for that is mistmatch between versions of blender and some DLL used by the addon (x86/x64). The other possible reason is that the DLL addon is not compiled for Windows at all. I assume your Blender is most likely x64, so you might need to check if the addon is available in x64 distribution as well.

Can't say more without closely looking at the addon itself.